# C++ IDE BEAN 1.6.9 issue

Tags: c++, cout

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; //error here

int main()
{
    cout << "COME AT ME BRO!\n"; //error here
    return 0;
}
```

cout is unidenfitiable. I had this issue earlier but my compiler didn't work so I reinstalled IDEBean and having the same issue again from square one. Help :?

Comment: ANSI/ISO C++ places **cout** in the **std** namespace, so add this line to your code : `using namespace std;` after include.

Comment: added the line just after include, still having the issue =/

Comment: also says that std is unable to resolve identifier

Comment: please update your code here. Also indicate what are the errors.

Comment: the errors are bolded(starred)

Comment: Post the *exact* code you tried to compile (copy paste from the editor) and also the *exact* error message when you compile the code. It doesn't matter whether intellisense is able to detect the `std` or not, *compile* your code and give the error message.

Comment: ^^^ Yeh, you're right Naveen. Any way on how I can get intellisense to bugger off then about the issue?   https://join.me/598-446-946  - for a desktop view of what i'm going through

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is inside `std` namespace. So you should use `std::cout<<"...";` or the other option is to do `using namespace std;` at the beginning and then you can use `cout<<"...";`

Answer (score 0):

```
 std::cout << "COME AT ME BRO!\n";
```

`cout` is defined in `std` namespace. So, you need to place `std::` before every `cout`. You are how ever have options -

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ; // Do this if you need include everything defined in the namespace
using std::cout ;     // If the program just uses cout of std namespace
int main()
{
    cout << "COME AT ME BRO!\n";   // Now you are free from keeping std:: before cout
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's all it says when I put my cursor over 'std' with a red line under it. "unable to resolve identifier std -- alt-enter for tips" and the tips just repeat it.

Comment: @Eric C - I amn't sure of how to deal with the problem. C++ compilers should compile the program after modifications. Me too not sure of what to do :(

Comment: Are you running the program on a Linux platform ?